# Realm Error with swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, realm

I am trying to use Realm and for some reason it keeps throwing an error.

```
void ObjectStore::update_column_mapping(Group *group, ObjectSchema &target_schema) {
ObjectSchema table_schema(group, target_schema.name);
for (auto& target_prop : target_schema.properties) {
    auto table_prop = table_schema.property_for_name(target_prop.name);
    REALM_ASSERT_DEBUG(table_prop);

    target_prop.table_column = table_prop->table_column;
}
```

}

That is the method that keeps becoming highlighted in the error.  Specifically the line

```
target_prop.table_column = table_prop->table_column;
```

The code that I am using for my data model is very simple so far its just.

```
import RealmSwift

class Workout: Object {
var setCount: Int = 0
var exerciseName: String = ""
var weight: Int = 0
var complete: Bool = false
var reps: Int = 0
var intensifier: String = ""
// Specify properties to ignore (Realm won't persist these)

//  override static func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
//    return []
//  }
}
```

Then the code I use in the view controller is simply just

```
func data() {
    var set = Workout()
    set.setCount = 1
    set.weight = 155
    set.exerciseName = "Clean & Jerk"
    set.reps = 8
    set.intensifier = "N/A"
    set.complete = false
    let realm = Realm()
    realm.write{
        realm.add(set)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was actually fixed in Realm this morning! (via https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2335)

Comment: So how do I fix it in my app?

Comment: You can either use Realm directly off of the `master` branch, but we plan on cutting a patch release in the next couple of days.